# How to do single global variable in Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm doing an `Android` project at the moment and I'm using Firebase in it. I'm going to be using FirebaseAuth and `FirebaseDatabase` in most of the `Activities` of the app, and it seems bizarre that I've got to set instances of them up in each underlying class for an `Activity`.

Is there a way that I can instantiate a single, global instance of these objects in my project so that I can reference them throughout?

I imagine I'd create a static class somewhere, something like

```
public static class GlobalVars {
    public static final FirebaseAuth AUTH = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); 
    public static final FirebaseDatabase DB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}
```

which I'd then reference in a different class using

```
GlobalVars.AUTH
```

but I'm not sure if this is good programming practice.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks :)

Comment: I think you want to use `singleton`

Comment: That approach will work.  You can even do a static import so you can just reference it as "AUTH" in your classes.

Comment: Isn't singleton bad practice?

Comment: You could have them all descend from some parent class that has those in it...I suppose :)

Comment: Firebase itself uses singletons, so you don't have to ;-) - FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() and FirebaseAuth.getInstance() will return the same instance every time you call them. Whether you do as above and assign them to final fields, or just call them in your code every time you need them, is up to you.

Comment: @joshsp98 I would say it depends on the use case.. Using singletons for every little thing is of course bad practice but I guess in this case it is better to use a singleton than to create an instance of it every single time.. Still you could also move everything that regards the firebase authentification to a util/service class which would seem way nicer to me

Comment: You are good with it. No need for a singleton.

Comment: Sorry @KlitosKyriacou, I only now noticed your comment. If you post it as an answer, I'' remove mine and upvote yours. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no worries, I just wrote a comment because I didn't have time to write a proper answer. But your answer is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Singleton` for that. To create it you can use the following code:

```
public static class FirebaseAuth {

    private FirebaseAuth instance;

    private FirebaseAuth() {
        // private constructor that nobody else can create an instance of your class
    }

    public static FirebaseAuth getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            //create instance if necessary
            instance = new FirebaseAuth();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

But your code is also working. Still I'd go along with the Singleton-Pattern as it is well known for most programmers.

**EDIT:** As @joshsp98 pointed out Singletons are considered as bad practice. [This article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/co-single/) provides pretty good information about when to use Singletons and when to avoid them.

Additionally @Klitos Kyriacou pointed out that Firebase already has this functionality built in - so maybe try that?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. As I commented above though, isn't Singleton seen as bad practice? When is a good time to use it and when is it not?

Comment: FirebaseAuth is an existing third-party class, not one the OP's is going to write.

Comment: @joshsp98 I really like that article: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/co-single/ I always use it when deciding whether to use a Singleton or not, but still most times I try to avoid it

Comment: @Klitos I don't have much experience with firebase therefore I didn't know that. But still the answer answers the question: "How to do single global variable in Java"

Comment: @Katharina that's a great article. Thanks

Comment: For future knowledge, I'm going to mark this as an answer as it answers my question about global variables but is not specific to my Firebase case. I'm going to stick with my solution taking into account other people's comments.

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` already does precisely (well, a bit more advanced version) of what your code does.

Answer (score 2):

The code for getting the instance of a Firebase feature is optimized for being called very frequently. It's totally fine to call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` in each class that needs it.

I tend to give each class a member field for each Firebase feature I use, that I then initialize in the constructor or `onCreate()` and use elsewhere in that class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Singleton, and the best way would be to use Enum's. Check out Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 3 - Enforce the singleton property with a private constructor or an enum type.

```
public enum FireBase {
INSTANCE;

public void firebaseInstace() {
// Your code goes here...
}
```

}

PS: Would also like to add that using Enum's would guarantee that your class is protected against serialization or reflection attacks.

Comment: i did not downvote as this is correct, but maybe some code?